# Validation to ensure value entered is a integer

Tags: vb.net, validation

I want a validation method that ensures that value entered is valid, it must be a integer (can include negative) and must not be blank. I have written this code, however not correct, can someone help me please. Thank you

```
If (b <> Integer Or " ") Then
            Console.WriteLine("Value entered must be a number")
        End If


new code:
Line98:
        Console.WriteLine("Please input the value of, B:")
        b = Console.ReadLine()
        If Not Integer.TryParse(b, New Integer) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Value entered must be a number")
            GoTo Line98
        End If
```

so i used a select statement, and if a user enters "abckak" any non numerical data i get an error Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "gakjdg" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

how could this be fixed, this is a quick example of my code

```
 Console.WriteLine("..........Main Menu..........")
            Console.WriteLine("Please input 1 ")
            Console.WriteLine("Please input 2")
            Console.WriteLine("Please input 3 ")
            Console.WriteLine("Please input 4 ")
            Console.WriteLine("Please input 5 for Help")
            Console.WriteLine("Please input 6 to Exit")

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your choice: ")

            Choice = Console.ReadLine()
            Select Case Choice

case1; etc

Case Else
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " & Choice & " is not a option, Please try again")
```

Comment: `If Not Integer.TryParse(b, New Integer) Then`.... This is a quick solution and would suit what you are looking for. Please [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) more there about the `TryParse`...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, i tried that however, and i input f lets just say, i get error Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "f" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [Integer.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2), it will try and parse the string into a integer if it can, if it *can't* it wont throw an exception...

```
 Dim b As Integer
 Console.WriteLine("Please input the value of, B:")            
 If Not Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), b) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Value entered must be a number")
    GoTo Line98
 End If
```

If it can parse the input from the user, then `b` would be the value from the parse, otherwise the value of `b` is still 0...

**Edit Per Comment**

```
Dim b As Integer
Do Until b > 0
    Console.WriteLine("Please input the value of, B:")            
    If Not Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), b) OrElse b <= 0 Then
      Console.WriteLine("Value entered must be a number and not equal 0")
      GoTo Line98
    End If
 Loop
```

Comment: @codexer one more question bro,  If (a = 0) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Error, number can not be 0, Please Try Again!")
            GoTo line93 'This will ask for input A again, and repeat the process until a is not 0
        End If
        If Not Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), a) Then
            Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "Error: Value entered must be a number")
            GoTo line93
        End If, how would i combine these two

Comment: @loco3424 with that statement than a/b can be less than 0. In your post you said numbers could be negative... Also if you have further questions please ask another one seperate from the original. Also if this has helped, please vote and accept if this solved your issue so others know this worked.

Comment: @codexer, yes sorry a can not be a negative, however problem with your code if i input a valid number it tells me Value entered must be a number and greater than 0 then continues, please help

Comment: I am confused, it seems you keep changing what you are asking. The current code will make sure a user enters a valid number and also make sure that number is greater than 0, if not it loops again...

Comment: @codexer, yes however before continuing it tells me Value entered must be a number and greater than 0 then continues despite me entering 9

Comment: @codexer, its fixed bro, one more question how would you use this validation for a select statement, if i put in "abc" an error apears Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "ksgdkjgd" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: If it's fixed and helped you, which you did confirm please mark answer as accepted and vote so others know this fixed your issue. Also, another friendly reminder, if you have further questions please ask another one seperate from the original.

Comment: @codexer, i can not ask more than 1 question per day, i had attached that question in this sub, please can you help me, i need to understand and complete this complex code tonight

Comment: You should be running the validation before even entering the select statement. Only if it passes the validation (it's an integer) do you allow it to exit the loop and go into the case statement. In `Integer.TryParse(Choice, b)` b will be your resultant integer, which you should be using in the select statement, not Choice.